# XPath and XNodes vs Xelements, whats better for mapping two large xml documents?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, mapping, xelement

I want to map two fairly large xml documents, one of them using the NIEM schema. I am most familiar with the System.Xml.Linq (XElement) class but have heard good things about using XPath and XNodes, contained in the System.Xml namespace.

Anyone have any pros and cons on the two in terms of mapping?

Comment: What exactly is 'mapping' in this context?

Comment: Mapping would be grabbing one element from Document A, e.g. "FirstName" and extracting the value of that element as well as some attribute information, and then inserting the value and attribute(s) into Document B's "FirstName" element.

Comment: This can be done very easily with XSLT. Please. provide the DocumentA and DocumentB (but in as minimal form as possible), and I'll be glad to give my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue (as you have large XML documents) is whether you need write access or not. If you're mapping from one file to a new file you can use an `XmlReader` which gives only forward read only access to the xml document but it is really fast.

I would say however that using XPath is less intuitive than `XElement` as most programmers are familiar with Linq syntax but not everyone might be familiar with XPath queries.

Comment: I don't believe read/write issues will be too much of a problem. And you are right, I do find Linq easier to use and more intuitive.